# slide hidden div on an onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following php while loop code:

```
while (...($...)){
$convid = $row['ID'];

 echo"
<button onclick='getconvo($convid)'>open</button>


    <div class="convowrap"></div>
    ";


    }
```

and the javascript code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".convowrap").hide(0)
})
</script>

script type='text/javascript'>
function getconvo(id){
$(".convowrap").hide(0).delay(200).slideDown(500)
var convid = id;
$('.convowrap').load('fetch_info.php', {id : convid}, function () {

       // do something when success
  });
 }
 </script>
```

When i click on the button above that says 'open,' all of the div that says convowrap slides, but i only want the current div to slide based on the button that was clicked that was generated from the php while loop. 
If the php loop executed three times, when i click on the first button generated by the first loop, the convowrap div slides on all three entries generated by the loop.

What do I do? Please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all the divs have the same class so its functioning as you it is supposed to ...

As you have the div after the button you can replace

```
 $(".convowrap")
```

With

```
$(this).next()
```

Inside the function for both `.load` and `.hide`
(Whichever you want)

**more generic**

It may be more usefull to assign another class to each div like

```
<div class='convowrap dummyclass$convid'></div>
```

And on button click change the selector to match that class like

```
 $('dummyclass'+id)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As you are using inline onlclick function inside HTML, you have to pass `this` explicitly like `onclick='getconvo(this)'`.

Anyway, see the following fiddle and hope you wanted this workaround -

https://jsfiddle.net/nuhil/4scas2gh/

Code:

```
<button onclick='getconvo(this)' id="1">Button 1</button>
<div class="convowrap">Content First</div>
<br/>
<button onclick='getconvo(this)' id="2">Button 2</button>
<div class="convowrap">Content Second</div>
<!-- More pairs of (button and div) go here -->

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".convowrap").hide();
  })

  function getconvo(button){
      $(button).next().delay(200).slideDown(500); 
      // You could use toggle here like following for better UX
      // $(button).next().toggle("slow"); 

      // Anyway,
      // Get the id from button attribute but make sure you already set it by PHP
      var convid = $(button).attr("id");
      console.log(convid);

      // $(button).next().load('fetch_info.php', {id : convid}, function () {
      // do something when success
      // });
  }  
</script>
```